# Joblib doesn't see cython modules when n_jobs > 1

Tags: python, parallel-processing, cython, joblib, cythonize

I can't get joblib to see a cython function that I am defining, and am unsure why.

[Here is the minimal code example in a Google Colab notebook.](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1xuPA7qRXjyljUIrKt9msxWCjTyDYxMLE)

Minimal code example:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
```

> 

```
%load_ext Cython
```

> 

```
%%cython -a

cimport cython

def myfunc(int a):
  return a+1
```

> 

```
with Parallel(n_jobs=1) as parallel:
  test = parallel(delayed(myfunc)(i) for i in range(10))
  print(test)
```

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

```
with Parallel(n_jobs=2) as parallel:
  test = parallel(delayed(myfunc)(i) for i in range(10))
  print(test)
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_cython_magic_e890d3cd151f55a5800848bf00284fa3'
>   '''
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception: joblib.externals.loky.process_executor.BrokenProcessPool: A task has failed to un-serialize. Please ensure that the arguments of the function are all picklable.

I get the same issue outside of jupyter/ipython, when building the module with setup.py

Answer (score 1):

After reading around, the closest to an answer I could find is that the `loky` background was the problem. The solution is to use `with parallel_backend('multiprocessing'):`